# RestKit Integration issues "No Such File Or directory"

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4, restkit

I am using xcode 4.3.1 and i am going to implement RESTKit to my Project In that follows [This Step to integration of the RestKit.](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x)

When the Drag and drop the RestKit project to my project it's done but when adding the Link Binary with library then it's red then after restart the xcode then also same problem aries

[image]

then after i build the project and shows the Below Error and not Running the project,

[image]

and file structure of the my project given below
[image]

So any body can help to solve my error,

Thanks in advance for spanding your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

This is because sometimes you add a file and then delete it. It removes the file from your project but the reference remains there, or it may be that the file was deleted but the reference still exists - go to the Project Navigator > right click > add files to... > and add the file that was red.

Comment: i follow same process you explain then also same problem aries can you explain more briefly.

Comment: is your file exists there? in disk?

Comment: the files that show with red text are those which are not added to your project. you will have to put these files first in your projct directroy and then add this file using steps i asked u

Comment: Dear that file is already their then also shows red text shows.

Comment: aahh. delete that file from your project by cliking removeReferences only and add again. and that time check the box above the window which appears asking copy files....

Comment: Let's i try to this implement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10834/discussion-between-neon-samuel-and-the-saad)